# service bus explorer 2.6.5.0 unauthorized error

Tags: azureservicebus, explorer, unauthorized

I am trying to connect the Topic in Azure Cloud using service bus explorer 2.6.5.0 by connection string from my laptop, but got 401 error,

> <15:14:46> Exception: The remote server returned an error: (401) Unauthorized. claim is empty. TrackingId:4acae37e-7b78-4a10-9d02-db96c2e69f40_G8, SystemTracker:mytopic.servicebus.windows.net:$Resources/EventHubs, Timestamp:1/25/2018 8:14:46 PM

How to fix this?

Comment: In my case this error was caused by ";" at the end of connection string. I know, it looks silly but when I removed trailing semicolon from it it started to work.

Comment: It does need the:   Endpoint=    on the beginning too

Answer (score 1):

should use the bus connection string, I used the Topic connection string.

Answer (score 0):

You need a connection string which has Manage Send Listen rights  so  goto Settings >> Shared Access Policies   in Azure   and create one, then use that connection string  ... Otherwise you get an unauthorised 401 in the apps logs